# Upload file using Upload Component from ant design not working on localhost

Tags: reactjs, upload, antd

I have a react project configured with Roadhog and Ant design for User interface components.

For localhost it uses a proxy to call API services. All API calls work as expected except File Upload method. I tested from other place and the API is working, and also in production environment works, but my API receive no file on localhost.

**My code**:

```
<Upload
    action="/api/upload_file"
    listType="picture-card"
    showUploadList={{ showPreviewIcon: false }}
    headers={{ Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}}
    name="file"
    withCredentials
>
    <Icon type="plus" />
    <div className="ant-upload-text">Upload</div>
</Upload>
```

And my request looks like:

### Request General

> **Request URL**: http://localhost:8000/api/upload_file
>   **Request Method**: POST

### Request headers

> **Accept**: */* 
>   **Accept-Encoding**: gzip, deflate, br 
>   **Accept-Language**: en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8 
>   **Authorization**: Bearer f3618115e76f934934983ehn9RvpoN5ohGjrOoBm9E3LA9OeZbiJW 
>   **Connection**: keep-alive 
>   **Content-Length**: 9815 
>   **Content-Type**: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryrNrG4oEpcIkf8gp4 
>   **Host**: localhost:8000 
>   **Origin**: http://localhost:8000 
>   **Referer**: http://localhost:8000/messages/new 
>   **User-Agent**: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) > Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 
>   **X-Requested-With**: XMLHttpRequest

### Request payload

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryrNrG4oEpcIkf8gp4 
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Trenes_de_Buenos_Aires_Logo.png" 
>   Content-Type: image/png 
>    
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryrNrG4oEpcIkf8gp4--

### Issue on ant design

Github issue here: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/9361

Comment: what is console error? CORS error?